# Preview spreadsheet prior to excel download ColdFusion 11

Tags: coldfusion, adobe, coldfusion-11

I'm trying to export data from a query to an excel spreadsheet.  I used the following code to successfully download an HTML table to a spreadsheet via Chrome and IE (picked up from Raymond) but I am now looking for a way to display the data prior to download.  Currently this immediately downloads when the submit button is selected.

[image]

```
<cfset request.isIE = false />
<cfif cgi.http_user_agent contains "MSIE">
 <cfset request.isIE = true />
</cfif>

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=SearchResults.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel">
<cfset ThisOrganism="#Form.GenusSpecies#">

<cfquery name="BSAFbyOrganism" datasource="BSAFweb">
SELECT ID, StudyType, Chem_Name
FROM Summary
WHERE   GenusSpecies='#ThisOrganism#'
ORDER BY Chem_Name

</cfquery>
 <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="5px">
   <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>StudyType</th>
     <th>Chem_Name</th>
   </tr>
 <cfoutput query="BSAFbyOrganism">
   <tr>
     <td>#ID#</td>
     <td>#StudyType#</td>
     <td>#Chem_Name#</td>
   </tr>                  
 </cfoutput>
</table>

<cfset q= BSAFbyOrganism>
    <cfset filename = expandPath("./myexcel.xls")>
    <cfspreadsheet action="write" query="BSAFbyOrganism" filename="#filename#" overwrite="true">

    <!--- Make a spreadsheet object --->
    <cfset s = spreadsheetNew()>
    <!--- Add header row --->
    <cfset spreadsheetAddRow(s, "ID,StudyType,Chem_Name")>
    <!--- format header --->
    <cfset spreadsheetFormatRow(s,
        {
            bold=true,
            fgcolor="lemon_chiffon",
            fontsize=14
        },
    1)>
    <!--- Add query --->
    <cfset spreadsheetAddRows(s, q)>
    <cfset spreadsheetWrite(s, filename, true)>
    <cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=myexcel.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel" variable="#spreadsheetReadBinary(s)#" reset="true">
```

Comment: How are you generating the "spreadsheet" - and more importantly, how is your cfcontent returning the spreadsheet? I see no `variable` attribute or psuedo-spreadsheet code in the above. Without some sort of content, it will not work because there is nothing to *be* "downloaded" ;-) As an aside, the [IE11 changed how userAgent is handled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so the "MSIE" will probably fail.

Comment: [Compatibility changes in IE11: Here's the string for IE11 on Windows 7:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko`  Note the "Trident" instead of MSIE.

Comment: User performs simply query.  The data is displayed in table.  At the bottom is a button for download.  This calls the 'file.cfm' which contains the code for opening the query in excel.  There is a query in this form and also cfoutput for the data so the content is there if I understand you correctly.  I can post the entire example.

Comment: *The data is displayed in table* So you are returning HTML (that Excel can interpret), not a true spreadsheet object.  You do not need to post the whole example.  Just put together a *small*, hard coded, repro case.  Nothing fancy, just enough code to reproduce the issue and something anyone can test outside of your environment. The code above, plus a snippet of the html table should do it.

Comment: Using html tags to create downloads to excel became a bad idea when Office 2007 came out.  However, it used to work, which means that there are lots of code samples on the internet.  You will have better luck with `<cfspreadsheet>`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  It sounds like I would be better off trying to create a spreadsheet.  But this still does not solve the problem of why IE will not download the file while Chrome and FF will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some code from Raymond Camden's blog post that I was able make work for IE.  So the user queries data and they are brought to the table posted above.  On that page is a button to create a cfspreadsheet.  This button calls the same query again and at the bottom I inserted the code below which writes to a spreadsheet and off to excel.  There is probably a way to reduce a step, but for now this is working.  Thanks for pointing me towards cfspreadsheet.  Appreciate your time.  If I improve on it I will come back and post it.

```
<cfset q= Organism>
<cfset filename = expandPath("./file/myexcel.xls")>
<cfspreadsheet action="write" query="Organism" filename="#filename#" overwrite="true">

<!--- Make a spreadsheet object --->
<cfset s = spreadsheetNew()>
<!--- Add header row --->
<cfset spreadsheetAddRow(s,  "ID,StudyType,Chem_Name")>
<!--- format header --->
<cfset spreadsheetFormatRow(s,
    {
        bold=true,
        fgcolor="lemon_chiffon",
        fontsize=12
    },
1)>
<!--- Add query --->
<cfset spreadsheetAddRows(s, q)>
<cfset spreadsheetWrite(s, filename, true)>
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=myexcel.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel" variable="#spreadsheetReadBinary(s)#" reset="true">
```

Comment: *was able make work for IE*  Makes sense since you are now generating a "true" binary spreadsheet, rather than html which may be interpreted very differently depending on the client.

Answer (score 2):

Solve one problem at a time.  For downloading, create a simple spreadsheet wtih Excel and save it to a place available to ColdFusion.  Then try these tags

```
<cfheader
name="content-disposition" 
value="Attachment;filename=#NameOfYourFile#">

<cfcontent  file="#NameOfYourFile#" 
type="application/vnd.ms-excel">
```

Notice that the value attribute of the cfheader tag specifies attachment, not inline.

As mentioned in the comments, use `<cfspreadsheet>` to create the file from your query.